# javascript execute event on click

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have this code:

```
<input type="file" id="imgLoader">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add-img">Add</button>
```

I was following this approch: [How to upload an image to a canvas with Fabric.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715812/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-canvas-with-fabric-js)

```
document.getElementById('imgLoader').onchange = function handleImage(e) {
var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (event){
    var imgObj = new Image();
    imgObj.src = event.target.result;
    imgObj.onload = function () {
      var image = new fabric.Image(imgObj);
      image.set({
            angle: 0,
            padding: 10,
            cornersize:10,
            height:110,
            width:110,
      });
      canvas.centerObject(image);
      canvas.add(image);
      canvas.renderAll();
    }
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

Is it possible to execute that event only after an user click on button?

Comment: You want, let's say, image preview before uploading, and then decide will be image uploaded or not?

Comment: Nope, I have this html inside modal so there must be some button which user must confirm to start uploading

Comment: Where is the html for the confirm button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wouldn't make sense, when you click the button the file hasn't been selected yet, so it can't be loaded. It just triggers the file browser window.

```js
$('#imgLoader').on('click', function(){
  $('#results').html('I fired');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="imgLoader">
<pre id="results"></pre>
```

If you want to load the file in a different button you can do it:

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function handleImage(e) {
var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (event){
    var imgObj = new Image();
    imgObj.src = event.target.result;
    imgObj.onload = function () {
      var image = new fabric.Image(imgObj);
      image.set({
            angle: 0,
            padding: 10,
            cornersize:10,
            height:110,
            width:110,
      });
      canvas.centerObject(image);
      canvas.add(image);
      canvas.renderAll();
    }
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById('imgLoader').files[0]);
}
```

Just check if files is an array and if the [0] element is valid.

Comment: It can be if OP means another button. With the first he choose what to upload and when he has chosen the file hitting a confiramtion button the upload starts. Now it starts on change without a confirmation

Comment: Well that's possible.

Comment: well I'm showing this content inside a modal so it's not good if it just load and user dont have to confirm upload and so on. If there won't be selected any file I will add there some validation. I'm just asking if it's possible to start uploading it after the button is clicked.

Comment: thanks, I had same code but I forgot to change last line reader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById('imgLoader').files[0]);