# add image(by path) on canvas fabric js

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I know that using URL is easy like this

```
function imageOnCanvas() {
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("workCanvas");
  
    fabric.Image.fromURL(
      "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8f/Example_image.svg/600px-Example_image.svg.png",
      function (myImg, err) {
        canvas.add(myImg);
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

But the thing I need is adding image by path, not URL.
The image is on my computer and I want to add that image on my canvas.
How can I do this?

Comment: this should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/67996981/7693185

Comment: @ResetMara actually you don't have to do anything fancy. Just feed the `fromURL` method with your local path e.g. **./images/myImage.jpg**