# Uploading an image from computer to Fabric.JS Canvas

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, canvas, fabricjs

Are there any Fabric.JS Wizards out there?

I've done my fair research and I can't seem to find much of an explanation on how to add an image to the fabric.JS canvas.

User Journey:

a) User uploads an image from an input file type button.
b) As soon as they have selected an image from their computer I want to   place it into the users canvas.

So far I've got to storing the image into an expression, this is my code below:

```
    scope.setFile = function(element) {
        scope.currentFile = element.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();

        /**
         *
         */
        reader.onload = function(event) {
            // This stores the image to scope
            scope.imageSource = event.target.result;
            scope.$apply();

        };

        // when the file is read it triggers the onload event above.
        reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);
    };
```

My HTML/Angular:

```
            <label class="app-file-input button">
                <i class="icon-enter"></i>
                <input type="file"
                       id="trigger"
                       onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFile(this)"
                       accept="image/*">
            </label>
```

If you haven't guessed yet I am using a MEAN stack. Mongoose, Express, Angular and Node.

The scope imageSource is what the image is store in. I've [read this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226332/add-image-from-user-computer-to-canvas)

and it talks about pushing the image to the Image object with my result, and then pass it to the fabric.Image object. Has anyone done a similar thing that they can help me with?

Thanks in advance

**** UPDATE **** 
Directive defines the canvas variable:

```
            var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(attrs.id, {
                isDrawingMode: true
            });
```

Comment: does scope.imageSource get populated with something?  with what?

Comment: Yeah so i use it as an expression to put on an image tag to make sure its working. However I'm unsure how to take that image and place it on the canvas

Answer (score 2):

Upload image from computer with Fabric js.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function (e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (f) {
    var data = f.target.result;                    
    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
      var oImg = img.set({left: 0, top: 0, angle: 00,width:100, height:100}).scale(0.9);
      canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
      var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png', quality: 0.8});
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

```css
canvas{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file"><br />
<canvas id="canvas" width="450" height="450"></canvas>
```

Comment: hey i try implementing this code, but i got error on `canvas.getObjects()` when i `console.log(canvas.getObjects())` outside upload function, it returns 1 object, but if i call that inside `reader.onload = function (f) {` it returns 2 objects, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

once you have a dataURL done, you can do either:

```
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        // This stores the image to scope
        fabric.Image.fromURL(event.target.result, function(img) {
          canvas.add(img);
        });
        scope.$apply();
    };
```

Or you put on your image tag an onload event where you do:

```
  var img = new fabric.Image(your_img_element);
  canvas.add(img);
```

Comment: Does it not need to be converted to a binary object? to be placed on the fabric canvas?

Comment: if it is a dataUrl that displays ok in a src attribute of a image element, you do not need to do anything. fabric can handle it.

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll give this a go and get back to you!

Comment: Got a bit of a problem. My canvas is defined in a directive. (Look at update in question) and I'm storing an image in a directive. Wondering if you might know how i could define or get the canvas var in my controller?

Answer (score 0):

This is for drag and drop from desktop using the dataTransfer interface.

```
canvas.on('drop', function(event) {
    
    // prevent the file to open in new tab
    
    event.e.stopPropagation();
    event.e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.e.preventDefault();

    // Use DataTransfer interface to access the file(s)
    
    if(event.e.dataTransfer.files.length > 0){

        var files = event.e.dataTransfer.files;
        
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

            // Only process image files.
            
            if (f.type.match('image.*')) {            
                
                // Read the File objects in this FileList.
                
                var reader = new FileReader();
                
                // listener for the onload event
                
                reader.onload = function(evt) {
                    
                    // put image on canvas
                    
                    fabric.Image.fromURL(evt.target.result, function(obj) {
                        
                        obj.scaleToHeight(canvas.height);
        
                        obj.set('strokeWidth',0);
                        
                        canvas.add(obj);       
                    
                    });
                };
               
                // Read in the image file as a data URL.
               
                reader.readAsDataURL(f);
            }
        }
    }  
});
```

**Resources**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/File_drag_and_drop