# where should i put controller code in a angularjs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I have just started learning angularjs and nodejs.
I am trying to build an app using fabric.js to upload pictures and edit it. I have seen a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513367/uploading-an-image-from-computer-to-fabric-js-canvas) here, the second answer is really helpful.

However when I tried to implement it in my own application I have faced problem. I use the [angular tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#prereq) for the application. In my own application I know I should put the last part of the code from the question linked in index.html, and put the middle part of the code in style.css. However, I don't know where to put the first part of the code, from my previous experience in extJS I know it should be a controller.

I tried to create a new file called controller.js under the same directory of index.html, paste the code there and include the controller into the index.html in the script tag, but it didn't work.

Here is the js code I am trying to implement

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function (e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (f) {
    var data = f.target.result;                    
    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
      var oImg = img.set({left: 0, top: 0, angle: 00,width:100, height:100}).scale(0.9);
      canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
      var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png', quality: 0.8});
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

Comment: Or maybe it is not about the script. I have checked the web in developer mode,  I have found that document.getElementById('file') return a null in my application.

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking here.  Also, are you trying to do this in Angular 1 or Angular 2?  You posted the tag for Angular 1 but your link is to an Angular 2 tutorial.

Comment: My bad. Already changed it to Angular 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the filereader, just have to call createObjectURL

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function (e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function (img) {
        var oImg = img.set({left: 0, top: 0, angle: 00,width:100, height:100}).scale(0.9);
        canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
        var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png', quality: 0.8});
    });
});
```

Comment: Sure. That is a really good suggestion. Since I just figured out my mistake is not even happened in these code, I am just going to put your post as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I find where I do wrong. There is nothing wrong with these backend code, it is in index.html, where I script the controller in the wrong place that caused the trouble. I have already solved that.