# How to Manipulate Image After Uploaded To Canvas (FabricJS)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I've been racking my brain on this for a while now, but I can't seem to rotate the image on Canvas after uploading. Here's the code sample in question:

```
  // INITIATE & DRAW CANVAS
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('CanvasArtArtboard');

    // CREATE OVERLAY GRIDS
    canvas.setOverlayColor('rgba(205, 173, 64, 0.6)', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));

    // UPLOAD USER IMAGE TO CANVAS
    document.getElementById('imgLoader').onchange = function handleImage(e) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (event) { 
            var imgObj = new Image();
                    imgObj.src = event.target.result;
                    imgObj.onload = function () {
                // start fabricJS stuff

            var image = new fabric.Image(imgObj);
                image.set({
                    originX:  'left',
                    originY: 'top',
                    padding: 0,
                    cornersize: 10,
                    scaleX: 0.4,
                    scaleY: 0.4,
                });

                //image.scale(getRandomNum(0.1, 0.25)).setCoords();
                canvas.add(image);
                image.sendToBack();
                            canvas.renderAll();

                //end fabricJS stuff
            }
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    }

    // ROTATE UPLOADED IMAGE
           $("#angle-control").click(function(){
            var curAngle = canvas.item(0).getAngle();
            canvas.item(0).setAngle(curAngle+15);
            canvas.renderAll();
          });
```

I've looked at the following example:

- [Add image from user computer to canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226332/add-image-from-user-computer-to-canvas) (Stack OverFlow Question)

  - http://jsfiddle.net/PromInc/3efe2x9j/

Once the user uploads their image and clicks the "rotate 90*" button, I'm looking for the image to then rotate.

EDIT: Apologies, here is my JSFiddle in it's current state: http://jsfiddle.net/darnellcreates/oq6htzew/3/

Comment: Looks like in your fiddle, you have two elements that both have the `id` of `angle-control`, one being the range-input and the other being the "Rotate Image 90°" button.

Comment: Just updated it and removed the duplicate ID, but still not working

Comment: Whoops, forgot to also say you should add [jQuery](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js) to your external resources or change all the element getting from jQuery to `document.getElementById`.  I added jQuery to your fiddle after fixing the duplicate IDs and the button worked as expected.

Comment: Joseph, thank you. A bit of an oversight on my part. It's working now as anticipated...I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at your fiddle and there is a lot wrong. The code for rotating is ok (sort of) but the page is full of problems.

First there is no JQuery and you are using the JQuery `$` function as selector to access DOM elements. I do not see the point in using jQuery if all you are doing is using it as a selector, you use `document.getElementById` in some parts and `$` in others. This totally negates any benefit Jquery would provide.

Second you are duplicating DOM element ID's (This is a strict no no) DOM ID's must be unique to the page.

To get you on your way here are a few changes,

Change the slider element in the HTML to

```
<input type="range" id="angleControl1" value="0" min="-90" max="90">
```

Note that the id is unique to the page. I have also avoided the naming convention (did not make it `angle-control1`) as this is a simple page and I will take some shortcuts and access the DOM elements directly in JavaScript.

Next remove the click handler for the range slider and replace it with a mouse move event listener.

```
 // keep a copy of the last value so there is no needless rotates
 var lastValue = angleControl1.value;  // no need to search the node tree. 
                                      // you can access elements directly by 
                                      // their ID.
 // Listen to the mousemoves of the range control. Click, change will
 // only update at the end of the mouse down up process. This does not 
 // provide good user feedback 
 angleControl1.addEventListener("mousemove",function(){
    if(this.value !== lastValue){  // only update the angle if it has changed
      // set the angle to the absolute angle rather than relative as you had it
      canvas.item(0).setAngle(Number(this.value)); // Number() is me being pedantic
      canvas.renderAll();  // rerender
      lastValue = this.value; // remember the last value
    }
  }); // all done for this function
```

Note. Direct DOM element access can be problematic in some situations (if you duplicate ID's, use that id as a variable before the DOM has loaded, your page is sharing the global namespace, or someone is using an old netscape browser) but for simple pages it is the easiest and safest way (If someone has netscape they can't run the page anyway because there is not canvas element).

Also remove the other Jquery calls `$()` as they cause the page to crash and stop everything from running.

You need to use the DevTools in these types of situations. It will show you all the errors and give you warnings (FireFox) for bad habits. To access the DevTool hit f12 on most browsers.The DevTools console will list errors and provide a link directly to the code where it is happening. You can also step through the code line by line so you can see what is going on.

Comment: Blindman67, while it wasn't the solution I went with in the end, I would like to thank you for your detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

i updated your jsfiddle ,to work both the rotate button 90o and the range bar,
just in case you need it.

link: http://jsfiddle.net/rqevmp3y/1/

```
$("#angle-control").on('click', function (event) {
       console.log('rotate');
        var curAngle = canvas._objects[0].getAngle();

        canvas._objects[0].setAngle(curAngle+90);
        canvas.renderAll();
      });

$("#rangeControl").on('change', function (event) {
       console.log('rotate from range',$(this).val());
        var curAngle = canvas._objects[0].getAngle();
        canvas._objects[0].setAngle(curAngle+parseInt($(this).val()));

        canvas.renderAll();
      });
```