# Slider inside image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, slider

I would like to put a Slider inside an image (specifically an iMac), like they have on [unbounce homepage](http://unbounce.com/). I think I need a div and then jQuery, but I have no idea where to start.

The thing is the image inside the Mac changes, but not the iMac image itself.
If that helps, I am using WordPress, so I could use any plugin too.
Do you have any idea on how to do that?

Thank you,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVe98.png

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use HTML canvas for complex image rendering. 
You can potentially dynamically draw what you want, where you want I'm them. 
You can use canvas to rotate, move, overlay images and add listener to click events to it.

See here to start :
[Dynamically add image to canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944382/dynamically-add-image-to-canvas).
Or here:
[Dynamically add image to canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944382/dynamically-add-image-to-canvas)

Answer (score 0):

Late, but may be helpful (by increasing level of difficulty):

- Use the iMac image as a frame PNG, leaving its inside "empty" using transparency. Behind it, the slider
- Make a slider which every image is framde by the iMac
- Position an slider hovering the iMac image